# How can I reogransie data from different columns into one, Using Union or Coalesce query for geological database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, union, coalesce

I'm trying to write a query for a Geological database where some alteration data has been logged into a table, tblDHAlteration.

Using SQL Server 2012.

I want to re-organise the data in the table either as a query or in a view so that the various alteration codes, such as SER, SI, BIOT and GRAPH are placed into their respective columns as shown in the attached image.

I've tried creating multiple union queries and then coalescing the data. I ended up creating views, and this works, however I was hoping to avoid having to create multiple views to coalesce from. Is there an easier/more efficient way to write these?

Thanks for your help. 
Cheers

View AA:

```
(SELECT DATASET, HOLE_ID, Depth_FROM, DEPTH_TO, Alt_SER, Alt_SI from
(SELECT DATASET, HOLE_ID, Depth_FROM, DEPTH_TO, Alt_SER, NULL as 'Alt_SI' from 
(SELECT DATASET, HOLE_ID, Depth_FROM, DEPTH_TO, Alt1_Code as Alt_SER FROM tblDHAlteration where Alt1_Code = 'SER') A
UNION ALL
SELECT DATASET, HOLE_ID, Depth_FROM, DEPTH_TO, Alt_SER, NULL as 'Alt_SI' from 
(SELECT DATASET, HOLE_ID, Depth_FROM, DEPTH_TO, Alt2_Code as Alt_SER FROM tblDHAlteration where Alt2_Code = 'SER') B) AA)
```

View BB:

```
(SELECT DATASET, HOLE_ID, Depth_FROM, DEPTH_TO, Alt_SER, Alt_SI from
(SELECT DATASET, HOLE_ID, Depth_FROM, DEPTH_TO, NULL AS 'Alt_SER', Alt_SI from 
(SELECT DATASET, HOLE_ID, Depth_FROM, DEPTH_TO,  Alt1_Code as Alt_SI FROM tblDHAlteration where Alt1_Code = 'SI') A
UNION ALL
SELECT DATASET, HOLE_ID, Depth_FROM, DEPTH_TO, NULL AS 'Alt_SER', Alt_SI from 
(SELECT DATASET, HOLE_ID, Depth_FROM, DEPTH_TO, Alt2_Code as Alt_SI 
FROM tblDHAlteration where Alt2_Code = 'SI') B) BB)
```

COALESCE QUERY:

```
SELECT COALESCE (AA.DATASET, BB.DATASET) DATASET, COALESCE (AA.HOLE_ID, BB.HOLE_ID) HOLE_ID, COALESCE (AA.DEPTH_FROM,BB.DEPTH_FROM) DEPTH_FROM,
COALESCE (AA.DEPTH_TO,BB.DEPTH_TO) DEPTH_TO, 
COALESCE( CAST(AA.Alt_SER as nvarchar(25)),CAST(BB.Alt_SER as nvarchar(25))) ALT_SER,
COALESCE( CAST(AA.Alt_SI as nvarchar(25)),CAST(BB.Alt_SI as nvarchar(25))) Alt_SI,
From AA full outer join BB
on AA.Dataset = BB.DataSet and AA.Hole_ID = BB.Hole_ID AND AA.Depth_From = BB.Depth_From 
order by dataset, hole_ID, Depth_From
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
;with data as (
    select
        DataSet,
        Hole_ID,
        Depth_From,
        Depth_To,
        Alt_Code = Alt1_Code 
    from tblDHAlteration 
    union all
    select
        DataSet,
        Hole_ID,
        Depth_From,
        Depth_To,
        Alt_Code = Alt2_Code 
    from tblDHAlteration 
)
select
    data.DataSet,
    data.Hole_ID,
    data.Depth_From,
    data.Depth_To,
    Alt_SER   = max(pvt.Alt_SER),
    Alt_Si    = max(pvt.Alt_Si),
    Alt_Biot  = max(pvt.Alt_Biot),
    Alt_Graph = max(pvt.Alt_Graph)
from data
cross apply (values
    ('Ser',   'Ser', ' ',  ' ',    ' '),
    ('Si',    ' ',   'Si', ' ',    ' '),
    ('Biot',  ' ',   ' ',  'Biot', ' '),
    ('Graph', ' ',   ' ',  ' ',    'Graph')
) pvt(Alt_Code, Alt_SER, Alt_Si, Alt_Biot, Alt_Graph)
where pvt.Alt_Code = data.Alt_Code
group by
    data.DataSet,
    data.Hole_ID,
    data.Depth_From,
    data.Depth_To
```

Comment: Fantastic Pieter! Many thanks. I just had to add from tblDHAlteration and a few "," for under the cross apply section and its looks to be running great!